# Voyager for Laravel 5: Wrong paths for images

Tags: php, laravel-5, voyager

Having created a new user via Voyager, the avatar was showing as a broken image. I uploaded a new image, but the image remained broken.

I checked with Console in Google Chrome and found 3 404 errors:

> 2017-06-19 10:53:50.159
>   http://localhost:8888/storage/users/June2017/ypKlbqbATDbpnYctZBFp.png
>   Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404
>   (Not Found)
>
> 2017-06-19 10:53:50.256
>   http://localhost:8888/storage/users/June2017/ypKlbqbATDbpnYctZBFp.png
>   Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404
>   (Not Found)
>
> 2017-06-19 10:53:50.473
>   http://localhost:8888/vendor/tcg/voyager/assets/images/bg.jpg Failed
>   to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not
>   Found) When I looked at the project, the paths for the 2 storage
>   errors are: http://localhost:8888/storage/app/public/users/ and:
>   http://localhost:8888/storage/app/public/users/June2017

While in Media, I'm seeing similar path problems when navigating the folders:

> 2017-06-19 11:38:22.248 %7B%7B%20selected_file.path%20%7D%7D:1 GET
>   http://localhost:8888/development/PhpstormProjects/Search4Venues/public/admin/%7B%7B%20selected_file.path%20%7D%7D
>   404 (Not Found)

Anticipating the question, in `.env`, I have: `APP_URL=http://localhost:8888`

Is this a configuration error?

**EDIT**

A colleague with more experience than me has been through Voyager and found some inconsistencies, which he's attempted to fix.

In `app.php`, we've had to change:

```
'url' => env('APP_URL', 'http://localhost:8888/development/PhpstormProjects/Search4Venues'),
```

... to:

```
'url' => env('APP_URL', 'http://localhost:8888'),
```

In `filesystems.php`, we've had to change:

```
'public' => [
    'driver' => 'local',
    'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
    'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
    'visibility' => 'public',
]
```

... to:

```
'public' => [
    'driver' => 'local',
    'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
    'url' => env('APP_URL').'/development/PhpstormProjects/Search4Venues/public/storage',
    'visibility' => 'public',
]
```

However, he discovered other problems in `config/voyager.php`:

```
'assets_path' => '/vendor/tcg/voyager/assets',
```

... where it too appears to be missing `PhpstormProjects/Search4Venues` from the path:

```
http://localhost:8888/vendor/tcg/voyager/assets/images/bg.jpg
```

At this stage, we have no idea what else could be wrong with Voyager.

Comment: I have similar issues, as per docs I know that localhost:8000 should be .env values.

Answer (score 6):

Firs u need edit file .env:

```
APP_URL=http://localhost
```

to:

```
APP_URL=http://yout-site-url
```

After that u need edit the file fylesystem.php like this:

```
  'public' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
        'url' => env('APP_URL').'/public/storage',
        'visibility' => 'public',
         ],
```

I was helped

Answer (score 3):

Follow these steps:

1.Change **APP_URL** in the **.env** file to **your website url**.

For example:

```
APP_URL=http://localhost
```

to

```
APP_URL=http://127.0.0.1:8000
```

2.Create symbolic link by: (if not done yet)

```
php artisan storge:link
```

3.Restart your server (**must**. Otherwise chages will not be applied.)

Answer (score 3):

this is common problem that even official site of voyager is mention about just read this page https://voyager-docs.devdojo.com/troubleshooting/using-https

in summery just open file `filesystem.php` in the folder `config` and delete this line of code `'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',`

Comment: also, do note that you need to wrap Voyager::image('...') with asset eg. asset(Voyager::image('')). This is the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

**Update you .env file**

```
APP_URL=http://localhost:8000
```

**and then run**

```
php artisan config:clear
```

**last**

restart your serve

**this work for me.**

Answer (score 0):

This error sometimes usualy shown if we runing php artisan serve with default port like localhost:8000, but if you place laravel wit voyager in htdocs/www in your own server like xampp/mamp etc this error will gone,

So you can try :

1. Installing apache or stand alone webserver like wamp or mamp
2. place your project in htdoc/www folder, and don't forget to set .env app_url:localhost (or your domain without port)
3. change document root in apache config to  your project folder
4. acces http://[your_domain]/[your_project]
5. done..

thank's

Answer (score 0):

Updated .env file:

```
APP_URL=http://localhost:8000
```

Fixed issue

dont forget to restart the server

Answer (score 0):

Updated .env file:

```
APP_URL=http://localhost/voyager
```

And Updated filesystems.php

```
'public' => [
     'driver' => 'local',
     'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
     'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage/app/public',
     'visibility' => 'public',
 ],
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is change in .env

```
APP_URL = http://localhost
```

to

```
APP_URL = http://<whatever your site is called>
```

And then move to the pic files to

```
public users
```

For some reason voyager stores them in

```
public users\users
```

At least it did for me
Just check what URL Voyager creates for the avatars and move them into the public folder with the same URL.

Worked for me at least

Answer (score 0):

#### Change one line in *.env* file:

```
APP_URL = http://localhost
```

to

```
APP_URL = http://<your site url>
```

The command is used to remove the configuration cache file and created again.

```
php artisan config:cache
```

Answer (score 0):

if you using laragon, change

```
'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage'
```

to

```
'url' => env('APP_URL').'./storage'
```